# OCaml color console output

Tags: windows, ocaml, console-application

Is it possible to colour the console output with OCaml on Windows ?

It seems to be possible on a linux terminal : `print_string "\027[31m blabla"` but I cannot find any information regarding the Windows console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using ther Vanilla windows tooling..

Color management is not possible by default using the command ( ms dos ) console emulation.

Out of the box, the best you can get is by using the PowerShell command line interface instead and to configure the colors like explained [in this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406264.aspx).

In an opened terminal:

```
write-host -foregroundcolor Red "Hello"
```

will result in **Hello** printed in **Red** ...

***But this is not convenient at all..***

### A better solution provided by an external tool

The easiest way is to uses an external tool to do the job, but you'll need to install a kind of windows command line extension. 
A nice project can be found [HERE](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) it's called [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) and will directly interpret the ANSI codes the same way the Linux modern terminal emulators does.

Comment: Great, thank you! however, I could change the colors from a C# application with the default command so it seems able to support different colors... Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [ANSITerminal](https://github.com/Chris00/ANSITerminal)
.  I do not remember how good the Windows version is — I personally do not use that platform — but do not hesitate to fill issues or submit pull requests.

Comment: Not everything works but colors background and foreground work

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ANSI color support (and more) in `cmd.exe` you can use [clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/).